# AggCat.getAccountTransactions and account administrator charges

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

It's not uncommon for credit card accounts to have an administrative user who can see all charges in their company.  When querying such an account with AggCat.getAccountTransactions, all charges are pulled in, however, within any Transaction, there no property that points back to the transactions account number.

For example:

- Fred (acct# 1234) is a regular user with a $10.00 charge in his account
- Mary (acct# 6789) is the administrator of the all accounts (including Fred's).  She has a charge $24.00

When I query Fred's account, I just see the $10.00 charge...fine.

When I query Mary's account, I get both Fred's and Mary's charges, and from what I can see, there's no way to differentiate her from Fred's transactions.

Is there some part of the API that can help me differentiate Mary's query, or could the API be enhanced to add the real account number associated with the transaction?

In this example, an American Express Blue account was being queried, but I've seen similar arrangements with other cards.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added a question to their forum on this same issue: https://intuitpartnerplatform.lc.intuit.com/questions/875917-how-to-get-details-for-american-express-corporate-card?event=new_question

Answer (score 0):

The API's should be separating this information.

Please submit a support ticket so we can get more details about the account.